# How to check current date lies between two dates through SharePoint designer workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

We have a list called 'Employee leaves' which contains all employees future leaves by having 'Start date' and 'End date' in the format 8/11/2016. Now from SharePoint designer workflow need to check whether current date lies between these 'Start date' and 'End date'. How to achieve this? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Add an if condition like below and in value click on the ... ellipsis button and select current date for today.

[image]